# The implementation of the button "Ask"

Tags: html, css

I want to create this button "question":

[image]

but in the implementation I do not understand how to do it, it seems easy, but i can't do this.. =( idiot 
code which I did:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  }

.ag_question {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
span.block1 {
    background-color: #fb8f02;
    padding: 14px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #444;
}
.ag_question a {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 14px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="ag_question">
        <span class="block1">
            <img src="http://storage3.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0713/h_1468392215_2753574_1f123fce00.png" alt="">
        </span>
        <a href="#">Задать вопрос</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want the icon inside the link was....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `span` tag in `a` tag. like this:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  }

.ag_question {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
span.block1 {
    background-color: #fb8f02;
    padding: 14px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    margin-right:10px;
}
span.block1 img{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
 
.ag_question a {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 14px 12px 14px 0px;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="ag_question">
 <a href="#">
      <span class="block1">
        <img src="http://storage3.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0713/h_1468392215_2753574_1f123fce00.png" alt="">
      </span>
      Задать вопрос
   </a>
</div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Flexbox**. Remove floats and add some elements... Like this

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  }

.ag_question {
    width:150px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    align-items:center;
    border: 1px solid #444;
}
span.block1 {
    background-color: #fb8f02;
}
span.block1 img {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 8px;
}
.ag_question a {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="ag_question">
        <span class="block1">
            <img src="http://storage3.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0713/h_1468392215_2753574_1f123fce00.png" alt="">
        </span>
        <a href="#"><span>Задать вопрос</span></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I made all elements floating and `display:table-cell` to center the element :

https://jsfiddle.net/L1ehfdeq/1/